# How to make the div responsive when the resolution is changed

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I came across a problem that when i change the resolution of my screen the div goes to right side. I want it to be responsive and should stick to the place.

Here are some snapshots

**1024 X 786** (the specified area in red circle)

[image: Screenshot]

but at **1152 X 864**, this happens

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="icons pull-right">
    <a href="#" style="">
        <img src="~/Content/images/emaar_home.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="">
        <img src="~/Content/images/emaar_contact.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/Content/images/arabic.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS

```
.icons {
    width:108px;
    margin-top: -42px;
    margin-right:6.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use media queries to control responsive width designs

```
@media all and (max-width: 1152px){
.icons { 
  //here you can control class="ico"
 }
}
```

not only for width, you can control for particular height screens..

media queries not support ie less than ie9. We have only one way.. try this

1st download this jquery script from

https://gitorious.org/css-media-queries-for-ie/css-media-queries-for-ie/blobs/master/css-media-query-ie.js

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles1.css" media="only all and (max-width: 480px)" id="stylesheet-480" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css" media="only all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1024px)" id="stylesheet-1024" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles3.css" media="only all and (min-width: 1200px)" id="stylesheet-1280" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/css-media-query-ie.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

and another one thing. in your code menu and container image parts are aligning correctly, that icon part only have problem. I think you dont need to use media queries. U did some mistake on icon part. If u correct this it will work very well in all browsers even ie6 without media queries. If u let me check your code, i can done this.

In icon container you align by

> margin-right:6.5%;

```
.icons {    
margin-right:6.5%;
}
```

check how you aligned that top menu and bottom image container from right.

when you are using media queries u should understand on thing. you must order higher to lower. like this

```
@media all and (max-width:1280px) {
.icons { width:108px; margin-top: -42px; margin-right:6.5%; } 
}
@media all and (max-width:1152px) {
.icons { width:108px; margin-top: -42px; position:absolute; right:0px; margin-right:11.5%; }
}
@media all and (max-width:1024px) {
 .icons { width:108px; margin-top: -42px; position:absolute; right:0px; margin-right:6.5%; }
}
```

all the best...

Comment: i am encouraging another prob i.e the media query is working on 1280 and 1024 width but not working on 1152..

Comment: Can you tell me that how to make a style be applicable on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use bootstrap css for responsive design... here is the link to download the bootstrap ... all media queries are there... it will make easy for you...

http://www.twitter.github.io/bootstrap/‎

Comment: are you using the media queries ??

Answer (score 0):

I am using 3 media queries but its working on 2 i.e. 1280 & 1024. but its not working on 1152 now.
here is the code

> @media all and (max-width:1152px) {
>       .icons {
>           width:108px;
>       margin-top: -42px;
>       position:absolute;
>       right:0px;
>       margin-right:11.5%;
>       } } @media all and (max-width:1024px) {
>       .icons {
>           width:108px;
>       margin-top: -42px;
>       position:absolute;
>       right:0px;
>       margin-right:6.5%;
>       } } @media all and (max-width:1280px) {
>       .icons {
>       width:108px;
>       margin-top: -42px;
>       margin-right:6.5%;
>       } }